# Computer Science Papers - English Language Quality

Tags: publications, computer-science, academic-life, language

Do you have any suggestions on how it is possible for a non-English speaker to publish a paper in a top-level journal without asking a native speaker to professionally edit the paper and fix the mistakes?

CONTEXT: 
I wrote a couple of papers and each time the reviewers asked for professional English editing. On the other hand, I have read many published papers written by non-English speakers whose English level is similar or worse than it is in my papers, which makes me wonder. I'm getting the feeling that it is not fair for non-English speakers to be forced to pay for professional English editing (not to say that it is not always effective, as I've already had my paper pass through a professional translator).

**Edit:** To be more clear, my point is that in certain journals reviewers/editors use the English language as a reason to reject some papers, while certain papers with similar English level seem to get accepted. I do not want to get into details about what are the motives for that and what kind of publishing politics is behind that, I want to point out that it is a bad thing for science because native and non-native English speakers are not in the same position. English skills should not be used as a reason to reject any paper.

I understand that situation in academic publishing is not ideal, but all good people should do something to make it better and not pretend as nothing is happening. In my opinion, there are many bad things in academic publishing but the English language quality is one of the worst. Maybe we can not change the publishing politics, but we can eliminate the English language quality as a reason for paper rejection.

Comment: Nobody forces you to pay for professional editing. Writing English on a sufficient level to participate in the scientific discourse is a learned skill. Just like with many other skills you need for research (for example, programming or lab-work skills), you can either learn the skill or outsource them to some payed agency.

Comment: Was your paper rejected for english reasons ?. Having couple of papers rejected from top journals is not unusual.

Comment: @mystupid_acct The paper which was accepted at the end after professional English editing, had only that one problem after the review. Other papers are still not accepted because i have to do revision, but reviewers constantly ask for better English. I hope it is a "normal" thing for new authors to be rejected because of such reasons, but i can't be sure about that.

Comment: This is a strange post!  At first, you seem critical of authors who publish papers written with poor English.  Then you suddenly veer off into frustration with editors who have asked you to clean up your English. Regarding that last part, imagine that someone is trying to publish in your native language, but doesn't seem to have checked his text with a native speaker, with the result that some of the sentences make no sense, some require a lot of work to understand, and some have mistakes that make you laugh.  Yuck! //  Communicating effectively with others is hard work and takes real effort.

Comment: @aparente001 , s/he didn't write anything critical of authors who publish with poor English. You simply jumped into conclusions and took the chance to sound aggressive, imho. (Communicating effectively also involves effort for understanding.)

Comment: @Helen - Well, I am definitely having trouble understanding OP's point of view on this.  On the one hand, s/he describes having read many published papers with a poor level of English.  On the other hand, s/he is not happy about being required to obtain editing services for journal submissions.  I do find this confusing.

Comment: @aparente001 I think s/he means that there are random standards applied to the language level.

Comment: @Helen - Okay, there's no doubt that there's inconstency in journals' expectations and standards -- but I think OP would get a better reception to the question if s/he edited the question to have a less confusing point of view, and a more clearly defined question.  Right now it sounds like a bit of a dual rant.

Comment: I just edited the question making it more clear, in an effort to have it off-hold. Imho what the OP was asking was clear since the beginning, therefore I ask for the question to get off-hold. (I am afraid that s/he fell victim of his subjective phrasing, which shouldn't be a reason to hold an otherwise excellent academia-related question.)

Comment: I can't tell from this question whether OP is saying that the reviewers ask for prof. editing and reject based on that requirement (implied) or whether they accept a paper, but still ask for better editing (possible).  As I mentioned in a comment on my answer, I've often asked for a paper to be better edited by someone strong in English, but I've only rarely found it so unreadable that I rejected it solely on that basis.  It does happen.  // But whether it's rejected or simply advised to do better, I think it *is* fair for English language publications to try to publish readable papers.

Answer (score 3):

A few points.

- As a reviewer,  I have often been frustrated by the quality of the English and requested that it be edited better.  It is hard to review papers with extremely poor grammar and it will be even harder as a published paper.
- That being said,  I totally sympathize with the problem of authors who aren't native English speakers!  I couldn't possibly write a paper in another language.

So I think it is both fair and unfortunate to require English papers in English conferences to meet a minimal standard.  A fact of life.

What can be done?

1. As someone commented,  it's a learned skill,  and your English skills improve over time.
2. You may have colleagues with better language skills who can help.
3. You can pay someone.
4. Here's possibly a new idea,  or perhaps this is already done:  perhaps English speakers who have sympathy for non-English speakers without the financial resources can copy edit *pro bono*.  Someone would have to set up a site to play matchmaker.
5. *[EDITED to add an excellent comment and summarize it in the answer].*  Some universities and institutions offer proofreading services to their faculties: check if there is one in your home university. – *Massimo Ortolano*

I could see myself volunteering for such a task once in a while,  like a paper every month or two.  But I'm not prepared to support a site to automate the matches,  which would be necessary.  Maybe i can talk my teenager into doing it....

Comment: This is a really excellent idea. Although I'm not a native speaker I've helped with acquaintances' papers several times and I could see myself contributing ~1 per month through such a site - and I guess there are several other volunteers. Of course if someone sets it up it'll be even easier :) but in any case I'll catch up and see if this can go somewhere.

Comment: One resource is English Language Learners SE: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Btw I found this: http://www.sciencedit-dw.org/ They require a donation to non-profits and seem to deal with more than just language, so the focus is a little different.

Comment: @aparente001 lol, swype strikes again.

Comment: 5. Some universities and institutions offer proofreading services to their faculties: check if there is one in your home university.

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano No, there is not such a service at my university, but anyway, it would not be helpful. After writing my papers i always send it to professional English translator who is not a native English speaker, but their English level should be better than mine. Each time the reviewers wrote that i should improve English language. Once i sent the paper three times to English translator and again they found problems with English quality. I feel like an idiot and i believe many non-English speakers feel like that. Nobody respects our time.

Comment: @Backward No it's a bit different: in my university the author works side-by-side with the proofreader to improve the manuscript.

Comment: Backward,  you need a better proofreader ..

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano Simply, we don't have a native English speaker to proofread. We are forced to pay for that or to find someone who is willing to do it for free. I thought an advanced English level would be enough for journals, but obviously i was wrong.

Comment: @Fred Douglis It seems i need a native English speaker to proofread, not just someone whose English is on advanced level. That is the problem.

Comment: @Backward what I meant by better is, one good enough not to get these complaints. Most native speakers may qualify though I've known Americans who can't write at all. Some non-native speakers learn it so well they write like a native.

Comment: Can you provide a couple of sentences? This sounds very weird. Or, you had the bad luck to come across some scammer.

Comment: @Helen, I assume you're asking Backward to provide text that the editor thought was acceptable but the reviewer thought was bad English?  I don't think it's weird at all, nor a scammer, necessarily.  It can just be someone who thinks more of their English ability than they should, but that being said, they may still be sufficiently better than the author that they can turn something that is unreadable into something merely objectionable.  I've reviewed things with numerous errors that I said need better editing, but I've also (rarely) reviewed things that were so unreadable that I gave up.

Comment: @FredDouglis , yes, it's true that they might not be a scammer. But what strikes me as weird is that the OP's English is already rather good, to a level that even better English (by a pro) wouldn't get rejected by a journal. So I wonder if there's some actual text. But maybe this is getting too long...